# Reading in a text file into a collection issue

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file which has the following structure inside it:

```
Daily Rainfall Totals (mm), Weather Station,(Meteorological Office Climatological Station TY12SDF) 
John Smith, DRE, RED Division, data obtained DEC 2011 
Format=Year, Month, 1-31 daily precipitation values. Any entry set to -99.99 means that no data exists for that day. 
2010      1   1.10   5.50   0.00   7.80   1.80   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.70   0.70   0.01   0.60   2.40  14.30   1.00   0.30   1.20   0.00   0.00   9.90   0.30   1.10   0.40   0.01   0.20   0.10   2.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2010      2  10.40   0.00   3.00   0.90   0.00   0.30   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.10   0.00   1.00  10.00   3.30   0.10   2.90   0.00   0.01   0.01   0.00   5.20   0.01   9.90   9.00   0.00   0.01 -99.99 -99.99 -99.99
2010      3   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.10   0.00   2.20   9.00   4.70   2.00   2.50   4.10   0.90  11.10   3.90   0.01   0.30   5.60  17.40   0.30
```

I would like to read the values into a collection but I don't know which one I should use? This is because I intend to bind each of the years data into a GUI control.

I know how to read in a comma delimited data 1,2,3 like this:

```
File file = new File("sample.txt");
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
while (in.hasNextLine()){
  num.add(in.nextLine());
}
```

EDIT
But the problem is I would like to create a structure in the collection which will look like this after I have read in the file:
[2010] [1] [2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]
Where 2010 is the year, 1 is the month and the rest is the data.

How would I go about achieving this? Multidimensional array?

Comment: You are already putting the data into a Collection. How you use that collection is up to you; its source (if it is from a file or somewhere else) is not relevant to the GUI. Do you want to reformulate your question in a more relevant way?

Comment: I have amended my question, if you could have a look at this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps mock up a screenshot in paint, of how you'd like the data to be structured on the page. It might clear things up a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How should i go about reading the data into the collection so i can bind it to a GUI component in Java?*

One quite elegant option here, is to use a `ListModel` (Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html)). A `ListModel` can be used as a backend data store for a `JList`.

**Example**

You can use the `DefaultListModel` implementation.

```
ListModel listData = new DefaultListModel();
listData.add() // Populate your list model.

JList list = new JList(listData);
// Create the JList with the list data.
```